# N-Tier Architecture WebApi: NUnit - No suitable constructor was found

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, asp.net-core, nunit

I'm extremely new in this unit testing and NUnit testing.
When I'm trying to run below code... I'm getting the following error

```
namespace NC_BLUnitTests
{
[TestFixture]
public class ProductBLTests
{
    private IBLProductsRepo blRepo;

    public ProductBLTests(IBLProductsRepo _blRepo)
    {
        blRepo = _blRepo;
    }

    [Test]
    public void AddProduct_Test()
    {
        //Arrange 
        var expectedResult = new ProductVM()
        {
            Name = "prod 4",
            CreatedDateTime = DateTime.Now,
            Price = 65.89m,
            Status = (int)StatusEnm.Active
        };

        // Act
        int resId = blRepo.AddProduct(expectedResult).Result.Data;
        var res = blRepo.GetProduct(resId);

        // Assert
        Assert.Equals(expectedResult, res);
    }
}}
```

> No suitable constructor was found

Now, I searched many articles here but I don't understand anything at all.

Here is my business layer code that I'm trying to test

```
namespace NC_BLRepositories {
public class BLProductsRepo : IBLProductsRepo
{
    private IDLProductsRepo dlProductsRepo;

    public BLProductsRepo(IDLProductsRepo dlRepo)
    {
        dlProductsRepo = dlRepo;
    }

    public Task<Response<int>> AddProduct(ProductVM product)
    {
        Response<int> res = new Response<int>();
        try
        {
            res.Data = dlProductsRepo.AddProduct(product).Result;
            res.IsSuccess = true;
            res.Message = "Product Added Successfully";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            res.IsSuccess = false;
            res.Message = "Some Error While Adding Product: " + ex.Message;
        }
        return Task.FromResult(res);
    }

    public Task<Response<ProductVM>> GetProduct(int productId)
    {
        Response<ProductVM> res = new Response<ProductVM>();
        try
        {
            res.IsSuccess = true;
            res.Message = "Product fetched successfully";
            res.Data = new ProductVM(dlProductsRepo.GetProduct(productId).Result);
            if (res.Data?.Id == 0)
                res.Message = "Invalid Product";

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            res.IsSuccess = false;
            res.Message = "Some Error While Fetching Single Product: " + ex.Message;
        }
        return Task.FromResult(res);
    }
}}
```

and this is the Data Layer that is injected here and will go for testing in future.

```
namespace NC_DLRepositories {
public class DLProductsRepo : IDLProductsRepo
{
    private MyShopContext dbCtx;

    public DLProductsRepo(MyShopContext ctx)
    {
        dbCtx = ctx;
    }

    public async Task<int> AddProduct(Product product)
    {
        Product newProduct = product;
        dbCtx.Products.Add(newProduct);
        await dbCtx.SaveChangesAsync();
        return newProduct.Id;
    }

    public async Task<Product> GetProduct(int productId)
    {
        return await dbCtx.Products.Where(e => e.Id == productId).SingleOrDefaultAsync();
    }
}}
```

Please guide me, I have 0 knowledge of all these things and the internet is giving me all the basic articles only.

Comment: Since the error is a constructor error it is probably occurring on following line : Response<ProductVM> res = new Response<ProductVM>();  You code looks like it is at the server and is trying to serialize a ProductVM  to add to the response.  Are you missing a [POST]?

Comment: Nope... not missing a post... Also, I'm trying to test the method after post

Comment: Your post is never being sent because the model doesn't exist.  The model seems to be coming from a response.  You can't have a response before you send the request.

Answer (score 0):

The error is in the fact that your TestFixture requires an argument of Type `IBLProductsRepo` in its constructor but none is provided.

By default, when no args are given, NUnit tries to use the default constructor so the message indicates that there is no default constructor. That's slightly misleading, since you really want to provide an argument.

Arguments are provided to NUnit TestFixtures in various ways. The simplest is to use `[TestFixture(ARG)]` but that is not allowed in C# for a non-primitive class Type. Next best would be to use `[TestFixtureSource("xxx")]`, where xxx is the name of a static field, property or method  returning `IEnumerable<IBLProductsRepo>`.

Alternatively, if you are using the same repo for all tests, remove the argument and make it a singleton, which is accessed by the tests.